# Akka-HTTP: How to generate a route from a List?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Given a `List("segment1", IntNumber, "segment2")` how can one generate a Route? There seems to be no good way of doing this. I have tried `path(list.reduceLeft(_ / _))` which does not work as it's signature is `(T, T) => T`.

How can I achieve something like this? `path(List("not", "known", "in", "advance")) -> /not/known/in/advance`

EDIT:

This is the scenario - A string comes in as `"something/{pathParam}/somethingElse"`, I want this to translate into `"something" / Segment (or whatever value) / "somethingElse"`. To get the Segment value, I'm just replacing the whole string surrounded by "{ }" with that value, once it is in a list.

Comment: `list.reduceLeft(_ + "/" + _)`

Comment: @mfirry that won't work, once a non-like type is added to the list, we've lost our type coherence. The signature of reduceLeft is required (T, T) => T.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have by using `List("segment1", IntNumber, "segment2")` is that you lose the information about the types of the single `PathMatcher`s.

```
val l: List[Object] = List("tmp", IntNumber, "tmp2")
```

You're probably better off by assembling a `PathMatcher` using `/` in place of assembling this list.

Comment: I would like that convenience, but unfortunately I don't know the route well enough in advance to do (at least what I think?) you're talking about. I've edited the problem to give some further insight

Answer (score 0):

**Constructing the `PathMatcher`**

If you construct your `List` to only contain `PathMatcher` values:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatcher
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.PathDirectives._

val pathList : List[PathMatcher[_]] = List("segment1", IntNumber, "segment2")
```

Then you can use a fold function to create the ultimate PathMatcher which the `path` Directive can then be applied to:

```
path(pathList.foldLeft(Neutral)(_ / _)) {
   ???
}
```

**Caveat**

However, the resulting Directive type will be different depending on the contents of the List.  The example List in the question would create a `Directive1` (e.g. `Directive[(Int)]`):

```
path(pathList.foldLeft(Neutral)(_ / _)) { (intFromPath: Int) =>

}
```

Whereas a different List would create a `Directive0` (e.g. `Directive[Unit]`):

```
val otherPathList : List[PathMatcher[_]] = List("segment3", "segment4")

path(otherPathList.foldLeft(Neutral)(_ / _) {
  //no input parameter
}
```

Therefore, I don't know how useful it would be to abstract the PathMatcher elements into a List without also somehow dynamically constructing the function that the resulting Directive would be applied to.